# Was there a better way to make this template?

Tags: technique, mdf, template

I'm making a small end table out of plywood, and I decided to make a template out of MDF and then shape the actual plywood pieces with a router. The photos below show the basic shape of the leg pieces. On a bandsaw, cutting out this template would be a ninety-second job, but I don't have a bandsaw. I have a jigsaw, a hand saw (Western, not Japanese), a router (handheld, not table-mounted), and a handheld orbital sander. So shaping this template has turned into a tedious symphony for jigsaw, hand saw, and sander, requiring constant repositioning of the workpiece, etc. Basically, hand saw on the long straight sections, jig saw for places where I can't use the hand saw, sander for outside corners and tidying up.

All of which leads back to the original question: was there a better way to do this with the tools I have available?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you know the radius of those inside corners, you could buy a dowel of the appropriate size, wrap sandpaper around it, and sand to the line. That should save you endless fiddling with the jigsaw, where one slip means you're making a whole new template. If the inside corner radius is not circular, make _another_ template out of a piece of scrap (2x4 should work, but whatever's handy and will fill the corner) to match the corner radius, wrap with sandpaper, and use that for sanding.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand... why not use the jigsaw to cut just outside the line and sand for precision?  What am I missing?

Comment: *"On a bandsaw, cutting out this template would be a ninety-second job"* Aye, but it wouldn't yield a great template as-is. The surface the guide/bearing runs against should be as next to perfect as possible, and even a superior bandsaw cut is not that.

Comment: @Graphus Fair point.

Comment: @GregNickoloff The basic answer is my own limitations. I'm well out of practice, and it's a big clumsy saw that steers like a container ship. Not a good combo. If I give myself a safe margin off the line, I'll be sanding for weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain. Sometimes the right tool just isn't in the garage.

What I would do for the long straight shots is use the router with a straight edge. Either a bearing-guided template bit (easy, because you just put your straightedge on the line), a guide collar (involves offset math, so a bit harder), or (less preferred because a base isn't always dead center to the bit, *and* you have a slim workpiece) clamping a fence that the outer base of the router rides against.

Nibbling with the jigsaw seems like something the cursed do in a place of eternal damnation.

Comment: Yeah, it feels that way. Don't know why I didn't think of the router for this...